# Xpages best way to loop through selected docs in a view and make change in with dialogbox value

Tags: xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Unable to find out the solution!

I have a view (With in the Dynamic Panel) of documents with one of the buttons labelled **Mark Inactive** to move the selected documents to Inactive state with the reason.

**Error Log**

> 08/02/2017 03:40:33 PM  HTTP JVM:
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException:
>   javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action
>   expression 08/02/2017 03:40:33 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception
>   processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please
>   consult error
>   log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files

Code suspended in the below line in debugger

```
var dynamicViewPanel3:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.UIDynamicViewPanel = get Component("dynamicViewPanel1");
var docs1 = dynamicViewPanel3.getSelectedIds();
```

Where in I have two parts of code.

- 1st Step MarK InActive button has a  code `XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialogReason}");` to open the user dialog box with the InActive Reasons selection in **combobox**.
- 2nd Step: Where in Dialog box has **Ok** (following code added in serverside Script Editor) and **Cancel** buttons:

Dialogbox with Ok and Cancel buttons Image:

[image]

```
var dynamicViewPanel3:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.UIDynamicViewPanel = get Component("dynamicViewPanel1");
var docs1 = dynamicViewPanel3.getSelectedIds();
var dialogReason = viewScope.dialogReason;
var curdb1:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", "GPSHR.nsf");
if (dialogReason && dialogReason.length > 0) {
for(var i=0;i < docs1.length; i++){
        var docId1=docs1[i];
        var req:NotesDocument= curdb1.getDocumentByID(docId1);
        req.replaceItemValue("Status", "InActive");
        req.replaceItemValue(Reason, dialogReason);
        req.save();
        req.recycle();

                }
                }
    setConfirmationMessage( i + " - Resource Information made InActive" );
```

Comment: Sorry for that, Typo mistake.  however my component code has no typo mistakes. I am using the above ssjs code from Extension library Dialogbox to get the handle of  UIDynamicView Panel. Just want to know, Is there anything I am missing/limitation , when initializing.

Comment: Thats a pretty general error..... Did you look at error log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files as suggested in the error message? Can you post the content here so we can see if anything jumps out?

Comment: Have you tried just doing var dynamicViewPanel3 = get Component("dynamicViewPanel1");

Comment: Yes, Tried but not working. I have an extension pages dialog box on the same page as a dynamic viewpanel that has check boxes enabled. If I check some check boxes then show the dialog box, the selections in the view panel become unselected.

Comment: As mentioned, what errors do you get in the logs? This is going to give you some more meaningful information from which to troubleshoot better with. I've also noticed you use get Component("dynamicViewPanel1"); there should be no spaces and should be getComponent("dynamicViewPanel1");

Comment: `2017-08-08T21:37:11.213+05:30 SEVERE Error while executing JavaScript action expression  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase  `
 `2017-08-08T21:37:11.471+05:30 SEVERE CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request  `

Comment: Till this line in eclipse debugger  :                                                                    [var DynamicViewPanel1:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.UIDynamicViewPanel = getComponent("dynamicViewPanel1");   ]                                                                                                               **currentView "GPSHR.nsf!Employees by ActiveStatus" (id=1737)** 
 **count 35** 
 **hashCode 0** 
 **hashCode32  0** 
 **offset 0**
 **value char[35]  (id=1726)**

Comment: Unable to see the getSelectedIds(); property now.  Instead of specified property, I can see getValueBinding, getParent, getId.  Really It's frustrating. Please, Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Not sure it will help but the line req.replaceItemValue(Reason, dialogReason); should have quotes around "Reason" assuming thats the field name?

Comment: Are you trying to do this to documents in another database? Do you have correct access to said database and  documents? If you change your code to try and modify documents within the database your code is running from, does that work or also fail?